# Yarn picking wrong version of Node

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-lock.json

I have node version 12.16.3
which is working fine when

```
npm install
```

is done

but with

```
yarn
```

I get below issue 
@testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8". Got "15.0.0-nightly20200517b3ca8869a6"
error Found incompatible module.
Any idea?
I guess its taking node "15.0.0-nightly20200517b3ca8869a6" by default
but i have node 12.16.3 installed.

Things i tried:
yarn cache clean
Restart IDE
I tried removing this @testing-library/jest-dom library itself but then issue started flashing from other libraries which are working fine with npm.